# Django: Allow a user to create an account on the web app

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django project that I'm working on which will allow users to create an account, log in, and then do stuff on the application. I've got the basic django tutorial in my code, so I can add users via the admin site, and then they can log in and do stuff. But, what I really want to do is to create a section on the login page where the users who don't have an account can enter their name, username, and password, and then use these credentials to log in. I'm pretty new to Django so I don't have much of an idea on what to do. Here's pieces of my models.py, views.py, and login.html which should give you an idea where I'm starting.

Login views:

```
@login_required()
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            template_name = 'polls/index.html'
            context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {
                'latest_question_list': Question.objects.order_by("pub_date"),
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'polls/login.html', {
            'error_message': "Your username isn't active", 
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/login.html', {
        'error_message': "Your username doesn't exist", 
        })
class LoginView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "polls/login.html"
```

Models that apply:

```
class Student(models.Model)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

Login HTML:

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:logged' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<h1>Username:</h1>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<h1>Password:</h1>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

Let me know if you want to see any more code. Thanks for any and all help I get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a user registration form in Django a simple approach would be to have :

A view :

```
def user_register(request):
# parse your form here
# create the user here
# don't forget set the user.active = True and login the user
```

A html form :

```
<form>
<!-- Your HTML form should have the Username/Email/Password fields -->
<!-- The HTML should also have the Name field as if you access it later using user.first_name it would through an exception -->
</form>
```

If you're not adding any new properties to the user , you could use the inbuilt User model. But if you're trying to expand it - you could add a foreign key mapping into a new model, maybe like:

```
class UserWithMoreFields(models.Model)
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
# Your fields as you already have in your model.
```

That's about it really.
One quick observation though on your view :

```
@login_required 
# Your View should not have login_required , as this view calls for a user of your website to register for it .
```

Comment: Thank you, this is making more sense. I will try to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs section on the [built-in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms). UserCreationForm and SetPasswordForm should give you a basic idea. You could either use those in a view, or you could build your own with custom logic, based on those examples.